# Add a custom intro page

Tags: customization

I made an animation for an intro page with HTML, CSS,javascript and some images, it's all in one file, what do I need to do to, to display it first and then go to the regular template.

I've already found this topic that say how to redirect

[Creating intro page in wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162269/creating-intro-page-in-wordpress)

My question is more oriented to the folowing doubts:

- I need to add some PHP, to the existing code(the one I created)?
- Where do I put the file? wp-content/themes/MySelectedTheme?
- Where do I put the the images?
- Do I need to modify something in the dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean *I need to add some PHP, to the existing code* to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should put everything in the theme you're using. A lot depends on it's file organization. Basically you can put it anywhere in theme's scope, but it's good practice to maintain order in themes files, like have specific folder for images, scripts, views and other file types. Usually this structure is recognizable in the theme itself, so I advice you to hold to the structure.

But as I don't know your theme - for sake of this question lets create a folder called `intro` where you put all files related to intro. Then you might want to redirect to it from `functions.php` level. In very beginning of `functions.php` file I'd paste following code:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) /* if the visitor is a new */
{
    setcookie('visited', true, time() + 3600 * 24);
    include( 'intro/index.html');
    exit();
}
```

Where index.html or index.php would be file with animation you've created.

I must mention, though, that redirections and animations on the main page are bad practice from UX and SEO point of view as it will make waiting period for main content even longer. If an animation is truly needed then I'd rather try to fix it throught javascript, for example a div which would dissapear after few seconds instead of making redirection.